# Jquery splitter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the below code for jquery splitter plugin. But its not working.I got this code from web ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LX484/10/)).It's working in jsfiddle and not working for me in my system.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.detail-outer-wrap * {
    background-color: #81d948;
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    setupSplitters();
    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        var splitter = $('.k-content').data('kendoSplitter');
        var curSize = splitter.size('.a');
        splitter.size('.a', curSize === '30%' ? '0%' : '30%');
    });
});

function setupSplitters() {

    $('.k-content').kendoSplitter({
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        panes: [
        // A
        {
            resizable: true,
            collapsible: false,
            max: '90%',
            min: '33%',
            size: '70%'
        },
        // B
        {
            resizable: true,
            collapsible: false,
            max: '67%',
            min: '10%',
            size: '30%'
        }]
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="log">
  <button id="toggle">Toggle A's size</button>
</div>
<div class="k-content">
  <div class="a">hai</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any differences between the fiddle and your local instance?

Comment: You don't appear to be including the `kendo.all.min.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include all neccessary dependencies:

`jQuery UI` and `kendo.all.min.js` are referenced by the code in your fiddle (besides two external css files):

[image]
[image]

Note the shallow `3` next to External Resources. That's a sign, that there are three external ressources being referenced.

Add them to your local instance and you should be fine.